# Prevent Visual Studio Dev server, IIS Express and full IIS from processing static files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, iis-express, static-files

Using Visual Studio 2010 I put a breakpoint on `Application_AuthenticateRequest` today and noticed that requests for my images, css and js were being processed. I switched my web application project to use IIS Express and then full IIS, and my breakpoint was still hit on those static files

I was under the impression that full IIS at the very least would by default not serve those files through the ASP.NET pipeline. What am I missing here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding this to my web.config. I know all my static files will exist in these folders, so it works ok for my needs.

```
<location path="scripts, styles, images">
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="None" />
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that IIS is setup to serve static content.

See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/05/23/don-t-forget-to-check-quot-static-content-service-quot-in-iis7-installation.aspx).

Comment: i have that feature installed and checked. Are there additional steps to enable it per web application/virtual directory/file extension or something??

Comment: @qntmfred - Check your web.config and machine.config to ensure that there are no handlers that will fire for static content.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest putting your static files on a separate subdomain and use AWS S3